# binary list contains all possible options by knowing its length in python

Tags: python

i am trying to get a binary list contains all possibilities by providing the length of these possible lists , now i found a solution but it is not very handy to be used in other functions.

example : i want a list of lists each one represents one binary option of four digits.

if the length is 4 then the result should be the following.

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

what i have done is by the following code:

```
>>> [[a, b, c, d] for a in [0,1] for b in [0,1] for c in [0,1] for d in [0,1]]
```

Now , i am looking for a way that by knowing the length of each member binary list we can generate the big list without the need to type manually [ a, b, c, d] , so if is possible to generate the list by a function lets say L_set(4) we get the list above . and if we type L_set(3) we get the following:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

and by typing L_set(2) we get :

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
```

and so on.

After spending few hours i felt stuck here in this point , i hope that some of you can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a job for [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> n = 4
>>> list(itertools.product((0,1), repeat=n))
[(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1)]
```

Comment: Our answers crossed in the ether :)  The `repeat` parameter does what you are doing with `*n` here and is a bit clearer.

Answer (score 3):

I think the `itertools` module in the standard library can help, in particular the `product` function.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

```
for x in itertools.product( [0, 1] , repeat=3 ):
    print x
```

gives

```
 (0, 0, 0)
 (0, 0, 1)
 (0, 1, 0)
 (0, 1, 1)
 (1, 0, 0)
 (1, 0, 1)
 (1, 1, 0)
 (1, 1, 1)
```

the `repeat` parameter is the length of each combination in the output

Answer (score 0):

If you know the length to be `n`, then try this:

```
[list(bin(i)[2:]) for i in xrange((2**n)-1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [12]: list(product(range(2), repeat=2)
Out[12]: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
```